# Database Trees with MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a table of "admins" and what they control "units" each unit and admin are from a different table. I wanted to check if there is a connection between an admin and a unit. The number of levels down is unknown. This is my attempt so far. May I get some help?

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `isadmin`;
```

DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION `isadmin`(a_id INT(11), a_table VARCHAR(25), u_id INT(11), u_table VARCHAR(25))
    RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE `rtn` INT(1);

```
SET @a_id := a_id;
SET @a_table := a_table;
SET `rtn` := 0;

WHILE @a_id != '' AND @a_table != '' DO
        SELECT `unit_id`,`unit_table`
    INTO @u_id, @u_table FROM `admin` 
    WHERE (`admin_id`,`admin_table`) IN (@a_id, @a_table);
        IF @u_id = `u_id` AND @u_table = `u_table` THEN
                SET `rtn` := 1;
            SET @a := '';
        ELSE
                SET `rtn` := 0;
            SET @a_id := @u_id;
            SET @a_table := @u_table;
        END IF;
END WHILE;

RETURN `rtn`;
```

END//
DELIMITER ;

SELECT `isadmin`("1","user","2","group");

Comment: `CONCAT` --> `CONCAT_WS`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this syntax will work:

```
IN (`a`)
```

Instead, you probably need to use `CONCAT`, etc to construct the `SELECT`, then `PREPARE`, `EXECUTE`, and `DEALLOCATE` it.

But, I suggest you back up -- Try the `SELECTs` by hand until you have some confidence that they will deliver the desired results.  Only *then* try to turn it into a Stored Procedure.

Comment: Appreciate the input. I will start looking at that. Do you think there is a better way approach.

Comment: It is probably better to avoid the 'hierarchy' whenever practical.

Comment: I cannot It is the very core of the application being built.